# "A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found." What does this message mean?

Tags: iphone

I got this error message when building MyApp using a Distribution Provisioning Profile. 
However, it succeeded when built with a Development Provisioning Profile.

What does this message mean?

My device is an iPhone 3GS with iOS4 installed. I created a certificate following Apple's documentation and I created an App ID, Development Provisioning Profile and a Distribution Profile.

I created Build Info (create Distribution activity (duplicated Release) and selected my Distribution Provisioning Profile.

[Image Link http://a.yfrog.com/img706/5572/nhk.png](http://a.yfrog.com/img706/5572/nhk.png)

Answer (score 1):

the value of the`Bundle Identifier` Key within your info.plist file must match the App-ID that you have assigned to your provisioning profile in the portal.

another reason could be, that said provisioning profile is indeed not installed on the computer you're developing on. In that case you simply download your profile and open it. it will then appear in XCODE's Organizer Window.

hope I could help

sam